# Regular expression to bring everything within two | in same line

Tags: regex

I have a situation like this.

```
| N/A<br>
| Start a new process<br>
| test
 
test1
test2<br>

| hello<br>
| < br><br>
| http://google.com

''Some text inside quotes''
| Use some URL
```

My requirement is to get all the | in consecutive lines along with the text. Some text are having a new line.

This is what I want the text to be like after using a regular expression

```
| N/A<br>
| Start a new process<br>
| test test1 test2<br>
| hello<br>
| < br><br>
| < br><br>
| http://google.com ''Some text inside quotes''<br>
| Use some URL<br>
```

I tried out with some regex but I am unable to get it perfectly done. Can someone point me to some way to do this.

I am doing this in Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this pattern with a space:

```
[\r\n]+(?!\|)[ ]*
```

You didn't specify, so I'm using .NET-style regular expressions.

This works by replacing any number of CR and/or LF characters followed by something other than a pipe, and then followed by zero or more spaces, with a single space. This effectively joins the non-pipe-beginning lines and adds the space where it joins lines.

The `[ ]*` could just be put as  `*` (no brackets), I just like having my space characters explicitly called out in the expression.

Comment: Thanks @richardtallent your solution worked. I tweaked and customized it for my use though.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is that you activate the "dotall" mode of your regex engine, so that the . is matching the newline. But how you do this depends on your regex engine.

The next thing is if you use `.|* or .*|?`. The first one is greedy and will match till the last "sentence" in your string, the second one is lazy and will match till the next "sentence" in your string.
Also check it in this,I hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

I'd suggest not doing this with regular expressions, as I find them not to be necessary.

Why not read the file line for line, and every time the line does start with a pipe (|), you add it as a new entry in a data structure such a resizeable array, and for lines not starting with a pipe, you instead add the text to the last entry in the array?

This, for instance, will do the trick (in Perl, YMMV):

```
foreach (@rawlines) {
        push(@formattedlines,$_) if /^\|/;
        $formattedlines[-1]="$formattedlines[-1]$_" if not /^|/;
}
```